# Is there a way to get from the DOM the different values of an option?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a way of adding different articles from a dropdown list and add it to a table at the bottom. The result I need is something similar to this (the product is a book):
**Quantity - Title - Price/unit - Total Price**
Since the value of the option in the form is like this: `<%= book.title%> <%= book.price %>` I can't take the price by itself and put in another column for example.

I tried to create multiple values for one option and obviously it did not work.

Form code

```
<label for="book">Livres:</label>
<select id="books-list">
  <option value=""></option>
  <% @books.each do |book| %>
    <option value="<%= book.title %> -- <%= book.price %> dt"><%= book.title %> | <%= book.author %> </option>
  <% end %>
</select>
```

Javascript Code:

```
const addBookToList = () => {
  const booksList = document.querySelector('#books-list');

  if (booksList) {
    booksList.addEventListener("click", () => {
      const book = booksList.value
      if (book != "")
        booksList.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<br/>${book}`)
      });
    };
  }

export { addBookToList };
```

I need the result to be something like a table with each "book" element on a column:

```
Quantity - Title        - Price/unit - Total Price
01       - Book title 1 - 152€       - 152€
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Create an array containing all the books and give them an id. Then put that id as the option value. That way you can add as many properties to your books as you want without the need to change the HTML or cram everything about the book in HTML attributes. Do not use HTML as your data model if you can avoid it. Creating the table is then as easy as: 1) filter the books array to find the correct book. 2) loop over all the book properties to create a table cell.

Comment: several approaches are use `data-` attributes or pass array/hashmap of data to javascript variable using JSON and use selected value to search that data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the easiest solution you have data attribute that hold double semicolon separated values. You split it and you will get the real data. You can also use JSON for this (not sure about `&quot;` vs `"` in html attribute).

```js
document.querySelector('#books-list').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const option = e.target.selectedOptions[0];
  if (option) {
    const value = option.dataset.value;
    if (value) {
      console.log(value.split(';;'));
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="books-list">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option data-value="foo;;bar;;baz">foo bar baz</option>
  <option data-value="lorem;;ipsum;;dolor">lorem ipsum dolor</option>
</select>
```

For your case you can just `split(' -- ');` to get the values and then create table row (tr) with the data (if the booksList is table).